# Pass parameter to a View

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a view in a where clause ?. If its possible how can I write the following example with parameter ?

```
CREATE VIEW comedies AS
    SELECT *
    FROM films
    WHERE kind = $param;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Views can't have parameters, but you can wrap it into a function:

```
create function comedies(p_kind text)
  returns setof films
as
$$
 select *
  from films
  where kind = p_kind;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then use it like a table/view:

```
select *
from comedies('bla');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, at the end I simply extracted the `where` from the view:

```
CREATE VIEW comedies AS
    SELECT *
    FROM films;
```

When calling the view:

```
SELECT * FROM comedies 
    WHERE kind = p_kind;
```

Of course it might seems useless here, but in my use case it was justified.